# Type mismatch in Play controller action when recovering a future

Tags: scala, playframework, controller, future, partialfunction

I'm having a problem to return the correct type in a scala play controller method can someone give me a hint here? I'm using for comprehantion to deal with two service methods that returns a Future, and I would like to handle elegantly the result and the errors.

What is the best practice to do this?

```
 def registerUser = Action { implicit request =>
    Logger.info("Start play actoin")

    RegisterForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        BadRequest(views.html.register(formWithErrors))
      },
      formData => {

        val registerResult = for {
          reCaptchaOk <- registerUserService.checkRecaptcha(formData.gRecaptchaResponse)
          userId <- registerUserService.registerUser(formData) if reCaptchaOk
        } yield userId

        registerResult.map(
          result => Redirect(routes.DashboardController.dashboard).withSession("USER_ID" -> result.toString))
        .recover{
          e => handleRegisterError(e)
        }

      })

  }

  def handleRegisterError(cause: Throwable)(implicit request: Request[_]) : Result = {
    val form = RegisterForm.form.bindFromRequest
    cause match {
      case dae: DataAccessException =>
        val globalError = dae.getCause.asInstanceOf[PSQLException].getSQLState match {
          case "23505" => GlobalMessages(Seq(GlobalMessage(Messages("errors.db.userAlreadyExists") ,ERROR)))
          case _ => GlobalMessages(Seq(GlobalMessage(Messages("errors.system.error"),ERROR)))
        }
        BadRequest(views.html.register(form,globalError))
      case _ =>
        BadRequest(views.html.register(form))
    }
```

the error:

```
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\repos\scala\SocerGladiatorWeb\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\repos\scala\SocerGladiatorWeb\app\controllers\RegisterController.scala:56: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Throwable => play.api.mvc.Result
[error]  required: PartialFunction[Throwable,?]
[error]           e => handleRegisterError(e)
[error]             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You need a partial function to recover future failures:

```
    def handleRegisterError(implicit request: Request[_]): PartialFunction[Throwable, Result] = {
      case dae: DataAccessException =>
        val form = RegisterForm.form.bindFromRequest
        val globalError = dae.getCause.asInstanceOf[PSQLException].getSQLState match {
          case "23505" => GlobalMessages(Seq(GlobalMessage(Messages("errors.db.userAlreadyExists"), ERROR)))
          case _ => GlobalMessages(Seq(GlobalMessage(Messages("errors.system.error"), ERROR)))
        }
        BadRequest(views.html.register(form, globalError))
      case _ =>
        val form = RegisterForm.form.bindFromRequest
        BadRequest(views.html.register(form))
    }
```

then change the controller code to

```
  registerResult
    .map { result => 
      Redirect(routes.DashboardController.dashboard).withSession("USER_ID" -> result.toString)
    }
    .recover { 
      handleRegisterError
    }
```

Also note that you need an async action, i.e.

```
def registerUser = Action.async { implicit request =>
  ...
}
```

because you are not returning a `Result` but a `Future[Result]`. You can find more about actions in [Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync#returning-futures).

### Details

If you look at the docs of the `recover` method of `Future` (see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U>:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U])) you'll see that it needs a `pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]`.

Partial functions are just like normal functions but they might reject some values (for instance here, the recover method does not accept all exceptions, but only those specified in the body). 
Defining a partial function needs a special syntax. It's very much like pattern matching but with no match expression.

```
Future(someAsyncWork).recover {
    case my: MyException => ....
    case _ => ....
}
```

Here we are using a partial recover function inline, so the type will be inferred automatically but if you want to define the recover as a separate function you need to explicitly state its type.

### Advanced

The partial function syntax (pattern matching with no `match` keyword) is very concise and handy in most situations, but sometimes you need more than that.

For instance, note that using this syntax, we had to duplicate parts of the code (`val form = RegisterForm.form.bindFromRequest`) in the recover function.

Although in your case there might be better solutions but you can always convert a normal function to a partial function. First you need to define a function of the type `Throwable => Option[Result]` and then you can use [`Function#unlift`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Function$@unlift[T,R](f:T=>Option[R]):PartialFunction[T,R]) to convert it to the desired partial function. 
Also you can directly inherit from a [`PartialFunction`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.PartialFunction) and implement its two methods ([apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.PartialFunction@apply(v1:T1):R) and [isDefinedAt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.PartialFunction@isDefinedAt(x:A):Boolean)).

Comment: I'd like to also share my experience, try to recover all failures in one place, that leads to cleaner code, then you will have to define meaningful exceptions, and reuse them in similar cases. Play lets you [handle all errors in one place](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling), so you don't need to repeat yourself by `.recover(...)` in all controller actions.

Comment: this would be nice but how yow do for example if you have let say a duplicate insert exception from different service methods with different error descriptions and want to show that error to the user... btw I think I will accept your answer looks ok to me... I am new to play and scala and I appreciate all the feedback

Comment: You can carry the message in the exception, or actually a list of errors, exceptions should carry meaningful info (exception materialisation idea is exactly useful for this reason), then in your global error handler you can capture those errors and send them to client. Service layer classes are responsible to return exceptions (failures) with proper list of errors.

Comment: What do you mean by global error handler ... you mean that do not handle errors in the controller actions at all but in some other global way? Can you please point me to some resource? What I want to achieve is that when an error is thrown from the service layer the user stays on the same page and an red alert message is shown for example on the top of the form. I have seen the the global error handling in play documentation but this as I understand is useful if you wold like to redirect a user to an error page, but i want to stay on the form and just show a user an error on top of the form